# Remove core data model on iOS app update

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, core-data, core-data-migration

My question is related to migration. I cannot do a lightweight migration as there are a lot of changes with attribute types and new relationships. I don't have time for a heavy weight migration since the code is not mine and needs faster delivery.

The workaround, which could work is when the app is upgraded, app should remove the old data and data model as the data is of no use and can be downloaded from the server again. On the app did finish launching, get the .db URL and just remove it and recreate it for the very first time after the upgrade?

After some research, all the methods are pointed to light weight migration. If there is a better way please assist.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) removeCoreDataAndReset{

      NSError *error;
      NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator = storeCordinator;
     for (NSPersistentStore *store in storeCoordinator.persistentStores) {
          [storeCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error];
          [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:store.URL.path error:&error];
     }
  // Initialise managedobjectcontext , Store Coordinator etc
}
```

Reinitialise all after this method as you do in statrt

Comment: That will leave the journal files in place. At best that might mean that the old data still exists. At worst it might crash the app since the data model has changed.

Comment: you need to reset datamodel too , In comments in i mentioned (Initialise managedobjectcontext , Store Coordinator etc) . This will help to avoid crash.

Comment: Regardless, leaving the journal files in place makes this code fail to achieve its goal.

Comment: Ok, Thanks ... i didn't  knew this.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the persistent store, you need to remove:

1. The actual persistent store file. This is located wherever you put it. You tell Core Data where it is when you call `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`, so if you're not sure, check there.
2. The journal files. These will have the same name as the persistent store file, but with `-wal` and `-shm` added to the end. **This is very important**, because in most cases nearly all of the existing data is in these files.

You can remove files with methods on `NSFileManager`. If you do this, do it **before accessing Core Data in any way**, i.e. before creating any Core Data objects of any kind.

Comment: So, 1. Remove all the .sqlite, .shm, .wal files and 2. reallocate persistance store, managed object model etc?

Comment: The part I mentioned in boldface about doing this **before accessing Core Data in any way** would mean that there is no persistent store, managed object model, etc to reallocate. You would remove the files as soon as your app launched, before creating those objects for the first time.